# Stopping or Interrupting a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to stop a java thread if it is running for 6000 milliseconds.

Below code to kill the Thread R1 is failed to stop the thread.  could you please correct code?

I have tried this code with     while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) to stop the thread.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    ThreadDemo(String name) {
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Creating " + threadName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running " + threadName);
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
                    // Let the thread sleep for a while.
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " interrupted.");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

public class Killthread {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Instant timeBefore = Instant.now();

        ThreadDemo R1 = new ThreadDemo("Thread-1");
        R1.start();
        System.out.println("Afte thread start");
        Thread.sleep(6001);
        Instant timeAfter = Instant.now();
        if (Duration.between(timeBefore, timeAfter).toMillis() > 6000) {
            R1.interrupt();
            // R1.stop();
            System.out.println("Thread Interrupted due to Time limitation.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks ok, though I haven't tried it yet.  What result do you see?

Comment: What's going on with the  `start()` method?  Can you just print your log and call `super.start()`?  I don't think there is a need for the nested thread.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two problems in your code, firstly that you aren't sleeping your main thread long enough, and secondly that you're interrupting the wrong thread.

`6001` ms isn't long enough to guarantee that your duration check will be true.  When I run your code, the main method rarely enters the if block.  If you change to it sleep for `6100` ms, it should consistently call the interrupt.

Your second problem is that you're interrupting `R1`, but you need to be interrupting `t`.

If you override `interrupt()` in ThreadDemo to pass the call down to `t`, then it will receive the interrupt and break its execution thread.

e.g.

```
@Override public void interrupt() {
    t.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you start a complete new, different and unnecessary thread in `ThreadDemo::start`.

```
@Override
public void start() {
    System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread(this, threadName);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

It should rather look like

```
@Override
public void start() {
    System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
    super.start();
}
```

And get rid of that `private Thread t;` in `ThreadDemo`.

Answer (score 1):

In please of calling t.start() from your overridden start method call super.start() which will call the start() of thread class, and is responsible to create new thread and register it with thread scheduler.